# SNES emulator without RetroPi?

Tags: emulation, games

I'm running Raspbian and I want to install a simple SNES emulator. I tried installing what seems to be the most popular one on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install zsnes
```

But the package doesn't seem to exist. Is there a simple NES or SNES emulator that I can just install with `apt-get`?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I'm wondering the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Try `piSNES`.
The official website is here:
[piSNES](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pisnes/)